# how to target specific row and copy data form that row using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

i have laravel bootstrap page where customer data came from foreach loop every customer row contains specific address i want to add button that copy its address so i used this code
html

```
<input type="text" value="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=+{{ $order->customers->location_url }}" id = "p1" />
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">Copy P1</button>
```

java script

```
 function copyToClipboard(element) {
 var copyText = document.getElementById("p1");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

but problem is taht i am using id and due to id it copy only first row of record even i use any other it copies first how i can pass specific so that it copy only specific record of table every order is stored by specific id that we can get by {{ $order->id }} i know i can use this but i dont know the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an id as a parameter in your function :

```
copyToClipboard('#p1');
```

But you never use this parameter in your actual function (the parameter element). Instead of that you use 'p1' all the time.

You should use it to target the row you want :

```
copyToClipboard('p1');

function copyToClipboard(rowId) {
    var copyText = document.getElementById(rowId);
    ...
}
```

Comment: so in input field i have to pass rowId="{{ $order->id }}" ?